# Maintaining both commented and minified source files

Tags: javascript, html, text-editor, css, programming

Is there a NotePad++ plugin that will maintain two versions of a file at once?

I want to maintain a commented css or js file **and** an uncommented version. The plugin should save two versions both with and without comments, for example `styles.dev.css` and `styles.min.css`, or `sitecode.dev.js` and `sitecode.min.js`